# Angular, valor por defecto de un input en template

Tags: angular, angular9

Estoy intentando asignar un valor por defecto al input "id_tarea" usando el valor de "registro.id" en un formulario en Angular (v9) y no sé como hacerlo. Intento:

```
      <input
      name="id_tarea"
      type="text"
      #id_tarea="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="registro.id" 
    />
```

y obtengo el valor pero al enviar al componente me recoge "null", sin embargo cuando envío el valor a mano de esta forma:

```
      <input
      name="id_tarea"
      type="text"
      #id_tarea="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="datoregistro.id_tarea" 
    />
```

Lo recibo perfectamente. Entiendo que ngModel determina el nombre del campo que envío. Pero necesito que el valor sea necesariamente el de "registro.id". Hay alguna manera de bindearlo desde la plantilla? Alguna solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he resuelto asignando el valor de GET a id_tarea en el componente:

```
export class DetalleComponent implements OnInit{
  datoregistro = {
   id_tarea: this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'),
 }
}
```

y en el template:

```
 <input
  name="id_tarea"
  type="text"
  #id_tarea="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="datoregistro.id_tarea" 
  />
```